# iOS 14 large-title navigation bar doesn’t come back after shrinking

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios14, large-title

My large title does shrink normally when scrolled, just like it's supposed to. But, it doesn’t come back large again even when I scroll to the top. When I build the project and open the app for the first time, the large title and search bar appear normally but once it shrinks. It doesn't come back before I finish the app. It happens the same on my device as well.

I am using `tableView` with `ViewController`, with `searchBar` in the `navigation title`. I also have `tableview header` under the navigation bar.

The way my large title works:

[image: preview 1]

The way it's supposed to work:

[image: preview 1]

I have added a `searchController` inside the navigation bar, but I don't think `searchController` is the problem because the same problem happens even when I remove the search bar from my project. Also, I have used the same code making large titles in those two different projects in the GIFs, but one works and one doesn't. Why is it?

I put this in the `viewDidLoad()` .

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

I also tried:

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

But, it didn't work.

I also tried putting:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

those two in `viewWillAppear()` but it didn't work as well.

**-Edit-**

The `tableView` is the first in the view hierarchy, as well. Please let me know if there's something wrong with the hierarchy.

The image of my document outline:

[image: preview 3]

Comment: Is your table view is the first controller in view of hierarchy?

Comment: @RajaKishan yep tableview is the first thing in the hierarchy.. it goes just after the safe area in the document outline.

Comment: You hierarchy is looks okay is my suggestion works? @SeohyunKim

Comment: dod you find the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up what `tableview.alwaysBounceVertical` is and what `bounce` is in `tableview`, and I found out that `bounceOnScroll` property was set to `false`, which was the reason this problem occured(I guess). The `large title` becomes large again when I scroll to the top, after I checked true to `bounce on scroll` in the storyboard.

Also, the my `large title` works fine without setting `bounce vertically` property to true. I tried with both storyboard and in code by setting it to false. So the problem was with only `bounceOnScroll`, I guess.

In code, it is okay to put

```
tableview.bounces = true
```

on the `viewController`.

Comment: Main problem with setting `bounces = true` is that you can't stop the large titles from stretching upon dragging table view down. If you want the stretching behavior to stop for some specific reason, you must set `bounces = false`.

Answer (score 1):

The possible problem is your tableview content height is almost same height of screen so it can't scroll and animates large title back. For that you can try always bounce function on your tableview. In viewDidLoad you can call

```
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

Probably this will solve your problem if tableview is first view of viewcontroller subviews hierarchy.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, either. The same problem happens. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: I found out how to fix the large title! Your answer has been the hint to the key of solving the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @SeohyunKim Please consider to post this as an answer here (with `Answer Your Question` button). You could even mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: @David Oh I didn't know there was such button here. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scrolling navigation bar to work correctly apart from the flag you set and the tableView position as first in view hierarchy you need to make sure that tableView top and bottom constraints are bind to superview . As default it's aligned to safe area which is incorrect.